# Some confusion in notation of Bernstein-Schroeder Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification

[Here](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/Cardinality.pdf) on page 232-233 the author offers a proof of the Bernstein-Schroeder Theorem. He uses the subset

$$\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty(g\circ f)^k(A-g(B))\subseteq A$$

and I'm not exactly sure how to parse this. Does this mean the union of the powers of the composition $g\circ f$? If so how is this a subset of $A$? I'm having a bit of trouble seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have the right interpretation. Notice that $g\circ f$ is a function sending $A$ to $A$, and therefore so is $(g\circ f)^k$ for all $k$.